# Add word before another when you find a certain word

Tags: java

I want to add "count (*)" in front of every "from" in a string.

Given: `Select thing1, thing2 from table;`

Output: `Select thing1, thing2, count (*) from table;`

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
String a = “ Select thing1, thing2 from table;”

String[] b = “form”.split(“\\s”)

For(string string: b){
If(a.contains(form)


}
```

Comment: What language is this? `For` -> `for`  `string` -> `String`  `If` -> `if` - plus mismatching braces

Comment: it is select thing1, thing2, count (*) from table;

Comment: does the query string changes?

Comment: Tag java language but use Keywords not correct ?.

Comment: Here's a link to the Javadoc for the String class.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  The Oracle Javadocs contain a wealth of information about each and every Java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int idx = a.indexOf("from");
System.out.println(a.substring(0, idx-1) + ", count(*) " + a.substring(idx));
```

**Output:**

```
Select thing1, thing2, count(*) from table;
```

Comment: It only gets the first index or occurence of "from". This wouldn't work when a string contains "from" multiple times.

Comment: thank you very much is what I was looking to do, I will look for those functions to know how it works, I am a novice in this